# An apparent bug in Geometry`ConvexHull2

Tags: symbolic, geometry, computational-geometry

I was replacing some usages of `` Geometry`ConvexHull2 `` with `ConvexHullMesh` and found one of my tests failing. It turned out the test asserted an incorrect expected result that agrees with the result of `` Geometry`ConvexHull2 ``, but is different from the correct result returned by `ConvexHullMesh` (most likely, the incorrect expected result got into the test from an invocation of `` Geometry`ConvexHull2 ``)

```
SetPrecision[Geometry`ConvexHull2[{{-99, 7}, {-93, -23}, {-90, -38}, {-76, -55}}], Infinity]
(* {{-99, 7}, {-93, -23}, {-76, -55}} *)

Element[{-90, -38}, ConvexHullMesh[%]]
(* False *)

SetPrecision[MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[{{-99, 7}, {-93, -23}, {-90, -38}, {-76, -55}}]], Infinity]
(* {{-99, 7}, {-93, -23}, {-90, -38}, {-76, -55}} *)
```

Is it an actual bug in `` Geometry`ConvexHull2 ``, or do I misunderstand something here?

Comment: a fix/workaround: ``Geometry`ConvexHull2[
 SortBy[Last]@{{-99, 7}, {-93, -23}, {-90, -38}, {-76, -55}}]``?